# Fill one column with data from one column in another table (randomly)

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table *Geometry* and another table *Customer* like this:

**Geometry**      **Customer**
City        ID    Location 
----         --    --------
Berlin       1    (null)
Paris        2    (null)
London

Now I'd like to fill the column *Location* with data from the column *City*. "Randomly" would be nice but it doesn't matter at all.

I've tried

```html
update Customer set Location = (select City from Geometry where rownum < 3);
```

but still getting this error: `single-row subquery returns more than one row`

UPDATE: I'd like to fill the whole column *Location* with one **update** statement. I'm using ORACLE. The result should look like this:

**Customer**
ID     Location
--      -------
1      Berlin
2      London

Does someone have any better idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Its more than one row because more than one result satisfies your condition. < 3 means 1 and 2 there for you will have more than 1 result

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server:

```
UPDATE 
    Customer 
SET 
    Location = (SELECT TOP 1 City FROM Geometry ORDER BY NEWID());
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it didn't work for me. I've also edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want it to pick one record at "random", you need to specify the correct number of rows:

```
update Customer set Location = (select City from Geometry where rownum = 1);
```

But note that since the subquery is not correlated to the `Customer` at all, the subquery may be optimised to only run once, and the same (randomly chosen) `City` will probably be used to update all `Location`s.

Comment: So like you said the same City (in my example it would be always Berlin) will be used to updated all Locations. Could you please take a look at my edited question? Thank you very much.

Comment: You said ""Randomly" would be nice but it doesn't matter at all." so by that logic, it is fine to set them all to one city (e.g. Berlin). Otherwise, you need to specify what logic to use to pick a city for each Customer.

Comment: Another approach (which would perform poorly) would be to create a function that returns a City at random, and call that function in the `set` clause. As long as the function is not embedded in a static query it will be called separately for each Customer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following, create a trigger on `customer`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customer_location
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF location ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NVL(new.location, 'X') = 'X')
BEGIN
    SELECT city INTO :new.location
      FROM (
        SELECT city FROM geometry
         ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
    ) WHERE rownum = 1;
END;
/

UPDATE customer SET location = 'X';
```

This will update the `customers` table with a matching, "random" location. The trigger will also produce a new "random" location when a record is `INSERT`ed into `customers` - as long as the location to be inserted is 'X' or `NULL`. (This wouldn't be wise if you actually have a location `X` - plug in some other value there!)

It is very possible to write a stored procedure to do the same thing, but you would have to create a cursor to loop over all the rows of `customers` where `location` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
update customer set location = 
  (select city from (
    select distinct c.id, g.city, dbms_random.value from customer c, geometry g
      order by value, city, id
    ) randoms where randoms.id = customer.id and rownum=1);
```

`distinct` necessary if there were two equal random values for one id